# Writing a new function for excel

Tags: javascript, c#, excel

I am looking for ways to write my own function in excel that I can use directly in cells, but I do not want to use VBA or COM. My preferred language would be javascript or C#.

I am using office 365, so I have the latest version of Excel. Also, it would be nice to make it work on Windows and Mac.

Comment: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=excel

Comment: The Office-JS API does not currently support UDFs

Comment: Thanks. This is what I suspected after skimming through the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out this answer found here on stackoverflow? It includes a link to Excel-DNA and some sample code to create your own functions.

[Creating new Excel formulas/functions with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132082/creating-new-excel-formulas-functions-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, this looks good. Thank you. I will try it and see if it applies to the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Although that is not going to work on mobile devices. It would be nice to have UDF that works with mobile

Comment: Excel does not (yet) support making UDFs that work on the mobile versions. Microsoft has said they might extend the JavaScript Office apps to support this in future.